# Execute function only if action hook fires

Tags: wordpress, function, hook, action

Can anybody give me a hint? :D
I want the function update_option only to be executed, if the action hook "pre-plupload-upload-ui" fires.

Actually it's loading on every page load.
Goal: Everytime the Upload Panel loads, the option should switch to "redirect" :)

```
function pz_action_pre_plupload_upload_ui(  ) { 
$download_method = get_option( 'woocommerce_file_download_method' );
    if ( $download_method && $download_method != 'redirect') {
        update_option( 'woocommerce_file_download_method', 'redirect' );
    }
}; 
add_action( 'pre-plupload-upload-ui', 'pz_action_pre_plupload_upload_ui', 10, 0 );
```

Comment: Are you executing another action that relies on the option after this action fires? You do not need to declare the accepted_args to 0 if there is none.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `did_action()` function to retrieve the number of times an action is fired.

- Source @ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/did_action/

```php
<?php

if ( did_action( 'pre-plupload-upload-ui' ) >= 1 ) {

  // ...

};


  [1]: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/did_action/
```